# How do I list NUnit 3 tests by their FullName?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to print the fully qualified name of each test using the `dotnet` CLI, but it's only showing the test method name. This list is kind of useless without more qualifiers!

```
> dotnet test -t MyTestLibrary.dll
Test run for MyTestLibrary.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following Tests are available:
    Test1
    Test1
    Test1
```

I would also be interested in printing the categories for each test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `.runsettings` file to define an NUnit section, where you specify the `DisplayName` format used.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <NUnit>
      <DisplayName>FullNameSep</DisplayName>
  </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

You can use it by calling

```
dotnet test -t MyTestLibrary.dll --settings test.runsettings
```

Comment: More info here: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html

Comment: great if you only have a single test library

Comment: @Ewan There are ways to run more assemblies. In my case I test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying *everything* to get this working, but I think it's not currently possible. I even tried this runsettings parameter:

> **DisplayName**
>
> The default for Test Explorer DisplayName is to use the Name of the test, which normally is the method name. Using DisplayName you can change between Name, FullName or FullNameSep. The last one will then use the FullNameSeparator, which defaults to ':'.

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html#displayname

But, that doesn't seem to do the trick. I don't know what the "Test Explorer" is, but, obviously, it's not working for the dotnet core test adapter.

```
$ dotnet test -t -- NUnit.DisplayName=FullName
Test run for C:\Users\anthony\...\MyTestLibrary.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following Tests are available:
    Test1
    Test1
    Test1
```

Comment: i just updated my project to NUnit3TestAdapter 4.0 and exactly that commandline worked - i got tests with namespace and class name (in F#)

Answer (score -1):

```
dotnet test -t -- 
NUnit.DisplayName=FullName
```

Comment: Please consider to add a little bit more context...